# Compiling Java code in terminal having a Jar in CLASSPATH

Tags: java, ubuntu, compilation, classpath, guava

**How can you compile the code using javac in a terminal by using google-collections in CLASSPATH?**

**Example of code trying to compile using javac in a terminal (works in Eclipse)**

```
import com.google.common.collect.BiMap;
import com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap;
public class Locate {
   ...
   BiMap<MyFile, Integer> rankingToResult = HashBiMap.create();
   ...
}
```

**Compiling in terminal**

```
src 288 % javac Locate.java 
Locate.java:14: package com.google.common.collect does not exist
import com.google.common.collect.BiMap;
                                ^
Locate.java:15: package com.google.common.collect does not exist
import com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap;
                                ^
Locate.java:153: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class BiMap
location: class Locate
        BiMap<MyFile, Integer> rankingToResult = HashBiMap.create();
        ^
Locate.java:153: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable HashBiMap
location: class Locate
        BiMap<MyFile, Integer> rankingToResult = HashBiMap.create();
                                                 ^
4 errors
```

**My CLASSPATH**

```
src 289 % echo $CLASSPATH 
/u/1/bin/javaLibraries/google-collect-1.0.jar
```

Comment: Programming questions should be directed towards stackoverflow.com. Please don't repost this question because it is in the process of being migrated there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  javac -cp /u/1/bin/javaLibraries/google-collect-1.0.jar Locate.java
```

or, new in Java 6, just let it scan the directory

```
  javac -cp '/u/1/bin/javaLibraries/*' Locate.java
```